# How to write SQL to select rows that has the max(value) of each group?

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

The table is like below:

```
employee, department, salary

Jack, 1, 400
Greg, 2, 350
John, 1, 450
Kate, 2, 420
Jane, 3, 300
Jessy, 2, 400
Kevin, 3, 380
```

I wish to do: Select the row that contains the highest salary of each department, I expect to return:

```
John,  1, 450
Jessy, 2, 400
Kevin, 3, 380
```

Here for department 1, John has the highest salary, so I select this whole row.

How to write this SQL?

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: What's the expected result if two persons in a department have the same max salary - do you want both of them or just one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.salary = (select max(e2.salary) from employee e2 where e2.department = e.department);
```

Answer (score 1):

select e1.* from employee e1 where e1.salary in (select max(e2.salary) from employee e2 where e2.department = e1.department);

Answer (score 1):

I typically solve that using window functions:

```
select employee, department, salary
from (
  select employee, department, salary, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as rnk
  from employee_table
) t
where rnk = 1;
```